# Use Javascript to get Maximum font size in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, font-size, max

I am drawing a canvas that needs to be on full available screen (100% width and height). I set the width and height of canvas using javascript like this

```
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  canvas.width  = w;
  canvas.height = h;
```

After setting the canvas, I need to draw some text in it which needs to get the maximum available font size. Please help me finding the way how can I display text with maximum font size. The text may contain a single character (both upper and small case) or a string and can also contain numbers. I need to do it with javascript not jquery.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use measureText()

Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099226/determine-width-of-string-in-html5-canvas

Comment: you want to optimize your font-size according to your window size?is this what you are talking about??

Comment: Yes exactly MESSIAH. I want the font-size in canvas according to the window size and string length.

Comment: JudeArasu, thank you for the link you have shared. I have implemented it and the only I am facing is that the text do not get vertically center aligned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Challenge

As canvas' `measureText` doesn't currently support measuring height (ascent + descent) we need to do a little DOM trick to get the line-height.

As the actual height of a font - or typeface - does not necessarily (rarely) correspond with the font-*size*, we need a more accurate way of measuring it.

## Solution

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/m2j10rzs/)**

The result will be a vertical aligned text which always fit the canvas in width.

[image: snap]

This solution will automatically get the optimal size for the font.

The first function is to wrap the `measureText` to support height. If the new implementation of the text metrics isn't available then use DOM:

```
function textMetrics(ctx, txt) {

    var tm = ctx.measureText(txt),
        w = tm.width,
        h, el;  // height, div element
    
    if (typeof tm.fontBoundingBoxAscent === "undefined") {
    
        // create a div element and get height from that
        el = document.createElement('div');
        el.style.cssText = "position:fixed;font:" + ctx.font +
                           ";padding:0;margin:0;left:-9999px;top:-9999px";
        el.innerHTML = txt;

        document.body.appendChild(el); 
        h = parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
        document.body.removeChild(el);

    } 
    else {
        // in the future ...
        h = tm.fontBoundingBoxAscent + tm.fontBoundingBoxDescent;
    }

    return [w, h];
}
```

Now we can loop to find the optimal size (here not very optimized, but works for the purpose - and I wrote this just now so there might be bugs in there, one being if text is just a single char that doesn't exceed width before height).

This function takes minimum two arguments, context and the text, the others are optional such as font name (name only), tolerance [0.0, 1.0] (default 0.02 or 2%) and style (ie. bold, italic etc.):

```
function getOptimalSize(ctx, txt, fontName, tolerance, tolerance, style) {

    tolerance = (tolerance === undefined) ? 0.02 : tolerance;
    fontName = (fontName === undefined) ? 'sans-serif' : fontName;
    style = (style === undefined) ? '' : style + ' ';
    
    var w = ctx.canvas.width,
        h = ctx.canvas.height,
        current = h,
        i = 0,
        max = 100,
        tm,
        wl = w - w * tolerance * 0.5,
        wu = w + w * tolerance * 0.5,
        hl = h - h * tolerance * 0.5,
        hu = h + h * tolerance * 0.5;
    
    for(; i < max; i++) {

        ctx.font = style + current + 'px ' + fontName;
        tm = textMetrics(ctx, txt);
        
        if ((tm[0] >= wl && tm[0] <= wu)) {
            return tm;
        }
        
        if (tm[1] > current) {
            current *= (1 - tolerance);
        } else {
            current *= (1 + tolerance);
        }            
    }
    return [-1, -1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/njgEq/1/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2 - 10;
var text = 'I M @ CENTER!';
context.font = '10pt Calibri'; //try changing values 10,15,20
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillText(text, x, y);
```

You can provide your conditions depending on the window size.Create a simple function like following:

```
function Manipulate_FONT(window.widht, window.height) {
    if (window.widht == something && window.height == something) {
        font_size = xyz //put this in ---> context.font = '10pt Calibri'
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the answer to question "how to get the maximum available font size"? This is just showing how to draw text aligned centered but only with static values.