# Text responding to window resize

Tags: dom, canvas, text, svg, window

So I'd like to have a paragraph of text which responds to changes in window size by adjusting the font or zoom such as it looks as big as possible while fitting into screen. I'd prefer to do it using SVG, but DOM and Canvas are options as well. I'm new to these stuff so any tips how should I proceed doing this? Link to similar answered question would be useful too, I just couldn't find one.

Thank you!

Comment: For canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627893/use-javascript-to-get-maximum-font-size-in-canvas/17631567#17631567

Comment: I think marking this as a duplicate was a bit premature.  The OP preferred an SVG solution. Closing it prevents anyone answering with one.  Anyway, here is an SVG solution (which happens to be a lot simpler than the Canvas approach).  http://jsfiddle.net/1vfcdxx4/

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's really very simple and useful!