# How do I make text gradient in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to fill my text with a top from bottom gradient. I've followed four or five different tutorials on how to achieve this but it doesn't work.

I have two different dynamic text sources, something like this:

```
<div id="first-name" contentEditable="true">Olaf</div>
<div id="last-name" contentEditable="true">Smith</div>
```

I want to draw whatever the user writes on the canvas (after a button press). I know how to fetch the values, so let's ignore that part and focus on two things:

1) How to know how wide the content is to fill with a gradient.

2) How to fill anything with a gradient to begin with...

They say this is how you should do it:

```
var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d')

var firstNameGradient = context.createLinearGradient(6,38,6,70) //no idea what values I should use

firstNameGradient.colorStop(0, '#eede85')
firstNameGradient.colorStop(1, '#fea700')

context.fillStyle = firstNameGradient

context.font = "bold 26px Tahoma"
context.fillText(firstName, 6, 38)

context.font = "bold 36px Tahoma"
context.fillText(lastName, whereFirstNameEnds, 38)
```

However, whatever values I try to fill with it doesn't work. In, fact nothing gets drawn in at all.

So I have no idea how to solve either **1)** or **2)**. Does anyone know?

**Edit:** Just noticed an error:

> TypeError: firstNameGradient.colorStop is not a function

Comment: Can't you use `$.width()` for 1)?

Comment: @JDong Yeah, probably. I haven't gotten to that point yet, really, since I want to try to fill anything at all first.

Comment: You want a background gradient, right? Not rainbow text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.createLinearGradient(6,38,6,70) //no idea what values I should use
```

This is defining a line from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) which in turn describes the angle of the gradient. Seems OK here, might need some fine tuning.

Change these:

```
firstNameGradient.colorStop(0, '#eede85')
firstNameGradient.colorStop(1, '#fea700')
```

to use `addColorStop()` instead

```
firstNameGradient.addColorStop(0, '#eede85')
firstNameGradient.addColorStop(1, '#fea700')
```

To find the width (in pixels) you can use `measureText()` and the property `width` of the returned object:

```
var tw = firstNameGradient.measureText(firstName).width;
```

Text is by default drawn with y representing the baseline. You can change this by setting text-baseline to top - this makes it easier to provide the gradient line:

```
firstNameGradient.textBaseline = "top";
```

The specs do provide a way to get the height of a font as well, but no browers has yet implemented this part so you need to either guess or use a [DOM element to measure height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627893/use-javascript-to-get-maximum-font-size-in-canvas/17631567#17631567).

Comment: Thank you. My biggest problem now is that it makes the text bolder, which makes it very hard to get the right X and Y values. Also, it seems very random which Y values are correct to begin from when filling the gradient.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for being so naive as to use w3Schools, but If you reverse engineer this snippet you should get the job done:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.font="20px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!",10,50);

ctx.font="30px Verdana";
// Create gradient
var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,c.width,0);
gradient.addColorStop("0","magenta");
gradient.addColorStop("0.5","blue");
gradient.addColorStop("1.0","red");
// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
ctx.fillText("Big smile!",10,90);
```

Should you need any more advice check it out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp)

---

**NOTE:**  Please, for the love of all things holy, don't use w3Schools, please try to use [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org)

**NOTE 2:**  I have no experience with canvas, so if I am making myself out to be an idiot, I am very sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ctx.measureText(txt)` to get the right width for the canvas. Here's an example that works as required:

```
var context = document
    .querySelector('canvas')
    .getContext('2d');
var pos = {x: 50, y: 50};
var txt = 'Hello!';
var txtHeight = 50; 

context.font = txtHeight + 'px Verdana';
var txtWidth = context.measureText(txt).width; 
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(
    pos.x, pos.y, txtWidth, txtHeight);

gradient.addColorStop(0,"red");
gradient.addColorStop(1,"blue");
context.fillStyle = gradient;

context.fillText(txt,pos.x,pos.y);
```

And here's the [demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/qzfbkdjd/1/)