# Is it possible to scale text inside <canvas> without breaking it down by screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Someone new to coding and first time poster as well. I have been working through a book on canvas and decided to try to make a simple "button" page that will essentially pull up a random "true" or "false".

I set my canvas.width/height to match that of the innerwindow. everything is seamless as i have a resize event except the text, as it stays static.  I know i can set it up in a fashion depending on the resolution of the screen, but as mentioned i'm looking for something completely  seamless as i resize the window so the text says centered to the "button" and scales with it. I've tried playing with context.scale with no avail. Is it possible?

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function() { canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerHeight; createPage();   }, false);

var canvas = document.getElementById("draw");

var context= canvas.getContext("2d");

function createCircle(){
context.beginPath(); // is this doing anything? it was working before i used it
context.arc(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2, canvas.width*(.09),0,360,false );
context.fillStyle="white";
context.fill();
//text              
context.fillStyle="black";
context.font="bold 1em sans-serif";
context.textBaseline="middle";
//little messy here trying to center the text
context.fillText("PUSH", canvas.width*(.44), canvas.height/2);
}


function createPage(){
canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
//blue
context.fillStyle ="#002db3";
context.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
//red
context.fillStyle ="#cc0000";
context.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height*(0.5));
//circle
createCircle();
}

//flash white,setTimeout(yes/no)
function hopeless(){
   context.fillStyle="green";
    context.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle="black";
context.font="bold 1em sans-serif";
context.textBaseline="middle";
context.fillText("NO ALL IS LOST", canvas.width*(.3), canvas.height/2);
    setTimeout(createPage,1000);
}

function hope(){
  context.fillStyle="blue";
    context.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle="black";
context.font="bold 1em sans-serif";
context.textBaseline="middle";
context.fillText("YES THERE IS HOPE YET", canvas.width*(.2), canvas.height/2);
    setTimeout(createPage,1000);    
}

 
function yesOrNo(){
  if(Math.random()<.50){
    context.fillStyle="white";
    context.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    setTimeout(hopeless,100);
   
    
  }else{
    context.fillStyle="white";
    context.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    setTimeout(hope,100);
   
    
  }
} 
createPage();
canvas.addEventListener("click",yesOrNo);
```

```html
<html >
<head >
<title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body >

  <canvas  id="draw" ></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks everyone!

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627893/use-javascript-to-get-maximum-font-size-in-canvas/17631567#17631567)?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
context.fillText("PUSH", canvas.width*(.44), canvas.height/2);
```

to:

```
var btnText = "PUSH";
var btnTextSize = context.measureText(btnText);
var textX = (canvas.width / 2) - (btnTextSize.width / 2);
var textY = (canvas.height / 2);
context.fillText(btnText, textX, textY);
```

[MeasureText API Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText)

Comment: Thank you @Jack, that was a very straight forward, easy solution for centering. Do you know anything in regards to scaling that text when resizing the window? Thanks again!