# How to calculate pixel width of given letter

Tags: javascript, user-interface, character, 2d, low-level

I'm attempting to implement the ability to draw text to the screen on a basic 2D plane, using only HTML Canvas and JavaScript.

I  start by setting up the canvas.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

I have a `keydown` event listener that appends to an array whatever characters I enter.

```
let characters = []
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.key.length === 1) {
        characters.append(event.key)
    }
}
```

I want to draw each character onto the canvas.

```
let x,y = 0;
characters.forEach(char => {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.font = "20px Arial"
    ctx.fillText(char, x, y)
    x += someValue // this needs to be calculated based on character pixel width
})
```

To avoid drawing all the characters at the same spot and overlapping, I have to increment the `x` coordinate by some value each iteration. This can't be a constant value, because characters differ in their pixel width ('O' is wider than 'I').

I need a way to know how much pixel space a character will take up, to determine what `x` coodinate to draw the subsequent character at.

I'm not looking for an HTML/JS specific answer. I want to know what the  general computer science approaches are to rendering characters with correct spacing to a graphical context. i.e, how does HTML itself do it under the hood?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine width of string in HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099226/determine-width-of-string-in-html5-canvas)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava That does solve my problem for now, but I've updated my question to specify a general lower-level solution rather a JS function that does it for me.

Comment: *I need a way to know how much pixel space a character will take up* -> the question linked gives you a way. For a lower level solution, perhaps its better to ask a new question with relevant info

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I've since updated my question with the relevant info, as I said in my last comment. I appreciate your solution, it works for now, but my application cannot rely on it long term as I plan to port it to other environments that may not have equivalent built-in functions. I need to know a generalized solution. I'd also like to know simply for my own computer science edification.

Comment: I understand, and would like you to get an answer as a generalized, language/framework/environment agnostic solution too, which is why I suggested asking a new question where you might ask about a low level approach to calculating pixel width of letters on screen.